# To remove leading alpha characters from string

Tags: regex, oracle

I have to Ignore the leading zeros, leading/trailing spaces, leading alpha characters from a string. Please help what regexp can be used.

For example:
the string is `abc123abc` , then it needs to return `123abc`.
Presently i used

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc123abc','([1-9]+[0-9]*)( *)$')
```

but it returns null for me.

Comment: Replace `( *)` with `(.*)`? Would this suffice?: `REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc123abc','[1-9].*$')`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc123abc'  from dual union all
  3     select ' 1234ddc'   from dual union all
  4     select '0abcd'      from dual union all
  5     select '18858 '     from dual union all
  6     select 'ab123ab45'  from dual
  7    )
  8  select col, trim(regexp_replace(col, '^[[:alpha:]]+| |0')) result
  9  from test;

COL       RESULT
--------- ---------
abc123abc 123abc
 1234ddc  1234ddc
0abcd     abcd
18858     18858
ab123ab45 123ab45

SQL>
```

Comment: the above solution removes zero when it is inside the number, I have to remove only leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Vaish,
This is how the Regex should be.

What this will do, it will remove any leading spaces, leading zeros.

**Example of query:**
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc123abc','[1-9]+.*')  from dual;`

You can see some examples I have tried here, plus you can test some more here too.
https://regex101.com/r/zfohRB/1

**Regex:** `'[1-9]+.*'`

**Explanation:**
`[1-9]` - This will look for the number to start. Excluding 0.
`+` - Quantifier + denotes 1 or more.
`.` - Means anything after that.
`*` - Means 0 or more. (You can replace this with `+` if you think that you need at least something after numbers.)

Good Luck